# How to resolve 'Cross Origin domain' issue without using 'CORS' chrome extension using Javascript to access JIRA REST API

Tags: javascript, rest, cors

I've developed an application to access JIRA REST API. By adding 'CORS' chrome extension, I'm able to get the data from **http://localhost:8000** by enabling 'CORS'

But the application doesn't work without CORS extension. 
Can someone please let me know is there a way to access the REST API without 'CORS' extension.

Comment: `How to resolve 'Cross Origin domain' issue without using 'CORS' chrome extension` - only one way (client side) ... the **server** needs to allow cross origin resource sharing - alternative, the server used to server the web page can proxy the request server -> server for the client

Answer (score 0):

**For me it worked by doing following steps:**

add a property in manifest.json

```js
"permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "notifications",
        "http://*/",
        "https://*/"
    ]
```

and try to request the rest API using jquery

```js
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "your jira server URL",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "authorization": "Basic <base64  username:password>",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }

  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```